# MySQL query is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT links.* 
FROM links
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT keywords_links.link_id
  FROM keywords_links
  INNER JOIN keywords ON keywords_links.keyword_id = keywords.id
  WHERE keywords.keyword
  IN ("facebook",  "google", "apple")
  GROUP BY keywords_links.link_id
  ) t
ON links.id = t.link_id
```

This returns the links that match a keyword(s). I have 3 tables: `links`, `keywords`, and `keywords_links`. The `keywords_links` links the keywords with the links.

How can I make this query more efficient? I'm inexperienced with MySQL so I had to use basic MySQL commands to create this query.

Tables (only relevant info displayed):

links:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=337789 ;
```

keywords_links:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords_links` (
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

keywords:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `keyword` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sort` (`id`,`keyword`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=60363 ;
```

Comment: Why do you need `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: 1. Show `EXPLAIN` 2. Show `CREATE TABLE` for every table.

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on all the columns used in the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: It probably doesn't make a difference in performance, but writing `SELECT DISTINCT keywords_links.link_id` is clearer than using `GROUP BY keywords_links.link_id`.

Comment: @zerkms: I forgot why I added it (I wrote the query a long time ago), but removing it slows the query by about 33% for some reason. The `CREATE TABLE`s were added, I don't know how to use `EXPLAIN`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html Just precede your select with EXPLAIN keyword

Comment: @zerkms Better yet, make a SQL Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @jpmc26: excuse me? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Sorry. I more meant "RE" your comment. I meant the OP should. Pardon my poor usage of @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe query itself is ok.  The performance problem is probably that it has to do a full-table scan of `keywords_links` to match the keywords and a full table scan on the keywords to find the matches.

Try changing the table structures to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `keyword` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sort` (`id`,`keyword`),
  INDEX (keyword)
) ;
```

This will speed up the keyword match (you can also use `create index`).

Next, so you can find the links faster:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords_links` (
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   unique (keyword_id, link_id)
);
```

The combination of finding the matches to the keywords through an index and then finding the links through an index should speed up the query.

Comment: As soon as it's innodb, then for `keyword` table the unique `keyword` index would be enough. So just 2 indexes in total: `PK(id)` and `UNIQUE KEY (keyword)`

Comment: @zerkms . . . You are correct.  In the question, the statement is `unique sort(id, keyword)`, which is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   l.*
FROM
 links l
 INNER JOIN keyworks_links kl ON kl.link_id = l.id
 INNER JOIN keywords ON kl.keyword_id = k.id
WHERE
     k.keyword IN ("facebook", "google", "apple")
;
```

**EDIT** Added *DISTINCT* to remove duplicates

Comment: What would make this run faster?

Comment: Because in the original format, he is creating an inline table (the subselect in the from) and then join that inline table with links table. The inline table will not use indexes for join, with this, mysql will use indexes (if is necessary)

Comment: Just a side note: query from the question guarantees no duplicate `link_id` in the nested query, while the query from this answer doesn't